# Excel - How to make a certain value set of numbers return different text values in another cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a certain cell in excel make another cell in excel say something specific. Example using cells J15 and J16:

If cell J15 has a number value greater than or equal to 1 but less than 2, then I want cell J16 to read Unsatisfactory.

If cell J15 has a number value greater than or equal to 2 but less than 3, then I want cell J16 to read Needs Improvement.

If cell J15 has a number value greater than or equal to 3 but less than 4 . I want then Cell J16 to read Meets Expectations.

If cell J15 has a number value greater than or equal to 4 but less than 5, then I want cell J16 to read Exceeds Expectations.

If cell J15 has a number value greater than or equal to 5, then I want cell J16 to read Exceptional.

So basically depending on the number in cell J15, I need cell J16 to either read, Unsatisfactory, Needs Improvement, Meets Expectations, Exceeds Expectations, or Exceptional.

Comment: Create a table with the lower threshold then use VLOOKUP()

Comment: `IF`, `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX MATCH`,`CHOOSE`.... you choose....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a formula with nested IF Statements (see below).  Your direction don't indicate how to handle the value of 1 or less, so that would return the word "FALSE" in J16.

```
=IF(J15>1,IF(J15<2,"Unsatisfactory",IF(J15<3,"Needs Improvement",IF(J15<4,"Meets Expectations",IF(J15<5,"Exceeds Expectations","Exceptional")))))
```

One or less could be handled by adding a result to the false condition of the first IF statement.

```
 =IF(J15>1,IF(J15<2,"Unsatisfactory",IF(J15<3,"Needs Improvement",IF(J15<4,"Meets Expectations",IF(J15<5,"Exceeds Expectations","Exceptional")))),"Your Text Here")
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment create a table with the lower thresholds and expected outcome:

[image]

Then you can use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(I15,O:P,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I would go with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the nesting the IF function is:

```
IF( condition1, value_if_true1, IF( condition2, value_if_true2, value_if_false2 ))
```

This would be equivalent to the following IF THEN ELSE statement:

```
IF condition1 THEN
   value_if_true1
ELSEIF condition2 THEN
   value_if_true2
ELSE
   value_if_false2
END IF
```

You can find more info here
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula: You just need to change the J15 to whatever you need.

```
=IF(J15>=1,IF(J15<2,"Unsatisfactory",IF(J15<3,"Needs Improvement",IF(J15<4,"Meets Expectations",IF(J15<5,"Exceeds Expectations","Exceptional")))), "Below 1")
```

(Note at the end you can change "Below 1" to say whatever you want it to say)